# Fix export to include character strings with accents (French text) in shapefile when using writeOGR in R

Tags: shapefile, r, rgdal

I have a `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame` in R that I want to export to shapefile.  I used `writeOGR` to export but the cells with that contain text values with accents (é, è, à, ê, etc) are blank. When I export only the data slot as a `csv` file, the values are preserved.

I have used the following when exporting:

```
writeOGR(obj=for.ana, dsn=".", layer="for_export",driver="ESRI Shapefile", encoding="UTF-8")
```

When I want to import a similar shapefile with French accents, I use the following code that works:

```
readOGR(".","file", use_iconv=TRUE, encoding="UTF-8")
```

What is the equivalent code for exporting?

[image]

Comment: For sure you could share test data that has one random polygon with attributes and values which are alike your real data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
writeOGR(obj=for.ana, dsn=".", layer="for_export",driver="ESRI Shapefile", layer_options = "ENCODING=UTF-8")
```

Instead of:

```
writeOGR(obj=for.ana, dsn=".", layer="for_export",driver="ESRI Shapefile", encoding="UTF-8")
```

With `layer_options`, you add the parameters to `ogr2ogr` shell command. Check [**GDAL documentation**](http://www.gdal.org/drv_shapefile.html) for more options.

Comment: @user3386170 ok. Edited and tested

Comment: When I opened the file in QGIS, I had to set encoding to `system` in order for the accents to display correctly (instead of UTF-8). An easy fix but odd given that the encoding is set to `UTF-8`.

Comment: Weird, I tested it with success. What is the output of `Sys.getenv('LC_CTYPE')` from R?

Comment: And for `Sys.getlocale()`?

Comment: `"LC_COLLATE=French_Canada.1252;LC_CTYPE=French_Canada.1252;LC_MONETARY=French_Canada.1252;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=French_Canada.1252"`

Comment: I have UTF-8 as default locale. This could explain this different behaviour, but is weird and I don't have a final explanation